Unable to install ctcdecode
I am trying to install ctcdecode using pip but I get this error:
Collecting ctcdecode
  Using cached ctcdecode-1.0.2.tar.gz (125 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t7lei6su\ctcdecode_0562497126b04a9186f962c9f35d1f7b\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
          download_extract('https://github.com/parlance/ctcdecode/releases/download/v1.0/boost_1_67_0.tar.gz',
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t7lei6su\ctcdecode_0562497126b04a9186f962c9f35d1f7b\setup.py", line 22, in download_extract
          tar.extractall('third_party/')
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2268, in extractall
          self._extract_one(tarinfo, path, set_attrs=not tarinfo.isdir(),
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2335, in _extract_one
          self._handle_fatal_error(e)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2331, in _extract_one
          self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2414, in _extract_member
          self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tarfile.py", line 2459, in makefile
          with bltn_open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'third_party\\boost_1_67_0\\libs\\geometry\\doc\\html\\geometry\\spatial_indexes\\rtree_examples\\specializing_index__indexable_function_object___storing_shared_pointers_in_the_rtree.html'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I need to use this as this is an dependency for a project so please don't suggest alternatives of this module.
I have tried to directly setup this thing from its Github page but I got an error there also.
I am using python 3.12 and windows 11
Edit:
I tried:
I enabled long paths in the registry
I realized the kenlm and threadpool folder was missing in the master folder of ctcdecode so I downloaded it from its github page and placed it inside a folder called 'third party'.
I tried installing different versions of torch and python
I have now ran into a different error:(the error is too big I can only share half of it)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Yash\Downloads\Compressed\ctcdecode-master\ctcdecode-master\setup.py", line 131, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 183, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 199, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 999, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_wheel.py", line 410, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 999, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 999, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 98, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 359, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 871, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 476, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 502, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 263, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 557, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 843, in win_wrap_ninja_compile
          _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1774, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
          _run_ninja_build(
        File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 2112, in _run_ninja_build
          raise RuntimeError(message) from e
      RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]

Edit 2:
I installed python 3.8 with pip version 19.2.3 an got this error:
Processing c:\users\user\downloads\compressed\ctcdecode-master\ctcdecode-master
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-707o2ed5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-707o2ed5\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-707o2ed5\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-707o2ed5\setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        download_extract(
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-707o2ed5\setup.py", line 21, in download_extract
        tar.extractall("third_party/")
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2026, in extractall
        self.extract(tarinfo, path, set_attrs=not tarinfo.isdir(),
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2067, in extract
        self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2139, in _extract_member
        self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2180, in makefile
        with bltn_open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'third_party\\boost_1_67_0\\libs\\geometry\\doc\\html\\geometry\\reference\\spatial_indexes\\boost__geometry__index__rtree\\rtree_parameters_type_const____indexable_getter_const____value_equal_const____allocator_type_const___.html'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

after this I upgraded pip to version 24.3.1 and got a different error related to torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hwtzx4l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 333, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hwtzx4l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 303, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hwtzx4l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 521, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3hwtzx4l\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 319, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]


in your registry, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem and set LongPathsEnabled to 1. Does that solve your issue?

Looking more closesly, it doesn't seem like windows is supported by the module you are trying to install, try in WSL

@FlyingTeller there is a different error now. Should I share that error

please update your question but as I said in the previous comment, I think in the end you will notice that windows just isn't supported by this

do you have Links?

If it is https://github.com/LearnedVector/A-Hackers-AI-Voice-Assistant then Quote: NOTICE: If you are using windows, some things may not work. For example, torchaudio. I suggest trying this on linux or mac, or use wsl2 on windows

@FlyingTeller yes it is this thing only. torch audio is working perfcetly fine on my system as I used this this code to download the most stable version of it for my system pip install torch==2.2.2 torchvision==0.17.2 torchaudio==2.2.2 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu  all I care about is ctcdecode problem.

Have you tried using WSL as I suggested?

@FlyingTeller i'll give it a try

The last commit for ctcdecode was from June 2021, and its PyPI release was in September 2020; Python 3.12 was reelased in October 2023. There is every chance Python 3.12 simply doesn't support ctcdecode (or one of ctcdecode's dependencies); it certainly won't have been tested with Python 3.12. So you should try and see if you can get it work with an older Python version, e.g., 3.9 or 3.10.

@9769953 I tried python 3.9 still the same issue. could the error be potentially related to the 'ninja' module because when I installed I got a different error mentioned above.

The Boost errors is, admittedly, slightly weird to me: with a Python version issue, I'd expect a compilation to fail, not a HTML to not be found.

Python 3.8 is clearly too old for a valid Windows-Torch version.

"After a bit of trouble shooting ": but what troubleshooting was that that you circumvented the first error?

there were many things I did and dont really remember which one fixed let me list all of them and update the question

For the original error, extraction the HTML file from the included Boost gzipped tar file, you may be running into the Windows file path limit. Which appears to be 260.
Some files included in the boost_1_67_0.tar.gz file are ridiculously long (because of namespacing reasons, apparently), such as boost_1_67_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_parameters_type_const____indexable_getter_const____value_equal_const____allocator_type_const___.html, which is 207 characters. That is neither the filepath you're seeing in the error, nor 260 characters, likely because

the filepath you're seeing in the error is the first in the tar-file that, extracted, exceeds the character limit. (If this one succeeded, another longer one would show the same error.)

the actual extracted filepath is longer: there is already the third_party directory prepended, plus if you're working in a virtual environment in a home/users directory of sorts, there are likely several subdirectories prepended, easily racking up to over 260 characters. (I'll leave as an exercise to the reader to calculate the
actual path length for the file path in the error.)



I don't have a direct solution, as I don't use Windows. Plus that it may depend on the version of Windows you are using.
But searching around for the path length limit on Windows and how to change it will possibly give you solutions. For example, I came across this relevant question on Superuser where I learned about the maximum file path length in Windows.
And the more official Windows / Microsoft documentation has e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry
Whether you can apply these changes to allow for longer path lengths without messing up your current system, I don't know.
Perhaps an alternative is to use the WSL; I have no idea if that will work. Here's a Reddit thread on that, and there are possibly other sources of information on this. Or perhaps it's quick and easy to try, and potentially safer than changing the Windows default path length.
Final note: I'm not saying this is the issue, but given the odd error, I find it very likely it is.

I enabled long paths in windows and got that error related to ninja which is also mentioned above(the second error I have shown above).

i inspected the file which is causing the error. in that file there is one line that uses subprocess too run the command "ninja -v" which gives the error "ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified."

@Yash that traceback suggests a compiler error (or an compilation attempt). Do you have a compiler installed, and is it on your path? To show the actual compiler error, you may have to set pip to be more verbose, with the -v or -vv or even -vvv option (perhaps on Windows, those options are /v, I don't know.

@Yash Also, compiling Torch sounds tricky enough. There should be prebuilt binaries for Windows, but perhaps the version wanted by ctcdecode doesn't have a prebuilt version for Python 3.12. Again, you shouldn't try to install an old package with a new Python version, unless you really know what you're doing.

@Yash Finally, the original question is fixed, as it was likely caused by the filename length limitation in Windows. This compiler build issue is another question, and should be another question.

I will update the question accordingly
